# Sintaxis SQL - LINQ en C#

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación en la que necesito guardar datos en SQL Server y verlos después en un Datagrid utilizando WPF. No estoy habituado a LINQ pero ya he hecho alguna prueba aunque no me queda muy claro por que hay dos tipos de sintaxis...

Ejemplo 1;

```
    var consulta = from x in bd.Tabla select x;
```

Ejemplo 2;

```
    var consulta = bd.Tabla.Where(x => x.Columna1 == "prueba");
```

En efecto, se trata de dos búsquedas diferentes, pero ambas dos se ven con cualquiera de la dos sintaxis...
¿Cual es mas recomendable hacer?

Y lo mas importante... ¿Hay algún sitio donde poder ver un resumen de las instrucciones INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE... para poder tenerlo a mano?

¿Como seria la sintaxis de la siguiente consulta si deseo hacerla utilizando los propios metodos?

```
    var consulta = from x in bd.Tabla select x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de `var consulta = from x in bd.Tabla select x;` el equivalente en la sintaxis de métodos sería

```
var consulta = bd.Tabla.Select(x => x);
```

Sin embargo el `.Select(x => x)` es la mayoría de los casos redundante ya que devuelve los mismo elementos sin modificación alguna por lo que podrías hacer simplemente:

```
var consulta = bd.Tabla;
```

La única diferencia entre esta última y la de arriba es el tipo de dato que devuelve.

La primera devuelve un IQueryable mientras que la última devuelve el tipo de dato de bd.Tabla (en caso de Entity Framework por ejemplo `DbSet<T>`)

La razón por le que existen estas dos sintaxis es simple.

Cuando el equipo de C# hizo C# 3.0 junto con NET Framework 3.0 agregaron muchas cosas nuevas al lenguaje entre ellas: lambdas, inferencia de tipos (var), métodos de extensión y métodos parciales, con el objetivo de poder implementar LINQ y su sintaxis de querys. El objetivo primordial era convertir el estilo imperativo en el que se hacían en ese entonces las consultas, selecciones, proyecciones y demás operaciones del álgebra relacional a un estilo declarativo lo más parecido a *SQL* que fuera posible.

Así que dada una variable

```
IEnumerable<Personas> personas = ....;
```

Un código similar a este

```
IEnumerable<PersonasResumen> mayoresDeEdad = new List<Persona>();
foreach(Persona p in personas)
{
    if(p.Edad >= 18)
    {
        mayoresDeEdad.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Se convirtiera en simplemente

```
var mayoresDeEdad = from p in personas
                    where p.Edad >= 18
                    select p;
```

La cosa se vuelve incluso mas complicada si tomamos en cuenta operaciones como JOIN

La sintáxis de métodos es solo el penúltimo paso para llegar hasta esa sintaxis y a veces es preferida porque en ciertos casos resulta mas corta por ejemplo en el caso que no se requiera hacer una proyección (select solo ciertos campos) lo anterior puede haber sido escrito de esta manera.

```
var mayoresDeEdad = personas.Where(p => p.Edad >= 18);
```

El select no es necesario en este caso, en la sintaxis de query sí es obligatorio.

Para mi la mejor explicación de LINQ está en esta entrevista prehistórica del 2005 del mismo maestro Anders Hejlsberg, creador de C#, LINQ y TypeScript. El video dura 37 minutos, tiene calidad baja y esta filmado con una cámara apuntando a la pantalla pero el contenido y explicación son oro puro.

[Anders Hejlsberg LINQ Demo 2005](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1MbdiPfYYI)

O si quieres una mejor calidad y tienes un poco más de tiempo este otro video del Lang.NET 2006 Compiler Symposium es también una excelente alternativa

[Anders Hejlsberg LINQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf2pNig8crw)

Por último solo te recuerdo que Insert, Update o Delete no forman parte de LINQ ya que como su nombre lo indica: **Language Integrated Query** es solo un lenguaje de consultas más no de operaciones con efectos secundarios sobre los datos.

Además funciona sobre cualquier `IEnumerable<T>` no solamente sobre bases de datos por lo que la forma de hacer `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE` depende del proveedor que se está usando, por ejemplo en Entity Framework:

INSERT

```
db.Personas.Add(persona);
db.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE

```
persona.Nombre = nuevoNombre;
db.SaveChanges();
```

DELETE

```
db.Personas.Remove(persona);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: +1 "La cosa se vuelve incluso mas complicada si tomamos en cuenta operaciones como JOIN".

Answer (score 1):

La única diferencia notable entre ambas es la legibilidad, hay quienes les resulta más sencillo utilizar/entender sintaxis linq declarativa
from x in bd.Tabla where (x => x.Columna1 == "prueba") select x;

mientras para otros resulta más natural utilizar las sintaxis linq por métodos
var consulta = bd.Tabla.Where(x => x.Columna1 == "prueba");

Aquí dejo las referencias
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Answer (score -1):

Yo utilizo la siguiente sintaxis

```
var query = (from a in informacionDB.departamentos
                    join b in informacionDB.empleados on a.ID_Empleado_Jefe equals b.id_Empleado into b2
                    from b in b2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join c in informacionDB.departamentos on a.ID_DepartamentoArea equals (int)c.ID_Departamento into c2
                    from c in c2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    orderby a.Descripcion
                    select new
                    {
                        a.ID_Departamento,
                        a.Descripcion,
                        a.Abreviatura,
                        a.Area,
                        b.Nombre,
                        Departamento = c.Descripcion
                    }).ToList();
        var query2 = (from d in query
                      select new gridDepartamentos
                      {
                          ID_Departamento = d.ID_Departamento,
                          Descripcion = d.Descripcion,
                          Abreviatura = d.Abreviatura,
                          Area = d.Area,
                          Nombre = d.Nombre,
                          Departamento = d.Departamento

                      }).ToList();
```

Esto es un Ejemplo de un LeftJoin  `query` es una List y `query2` es una lista de una clase personalizada `gridDepartamentos`

El siguiente es un ejemplo de un insert:

```
 var primerInsert = new huellas()
        {

            codigo = codigo,
            ID_Empresa = idEmpresa,
            finger_data = Data,
            NumeroDedo = numeroDedo
        };
        informacionDB.huellas.Add(primerInsert);

        informacionDB.SaveChanges();
```

Ejemplo para Update:

```
var queryTest = (from a in informacionDB.empleados
                         where a.Codigo == 10
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();
        queryTest.Nombre = "CambiodeNombre";
        informacionDB.SaveChanges();
```